# how to reference a flow variable in an expression filter?

Tags: mule

How to reference a flow variable in an expression filter?

Assuming that `myVariable` is a boolean, I tried:

```
<expression-filter evaluator="variable" expression="myVariable" />
```

but that did not work. Eventually I settled for:

```
<expression-filter evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getInvocationProperty('myVariable')" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *variable* expression is not complete and can't be evaluated to a boolean as is (while the Groovy probably can because the variable is a boolean).

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Expressions#UsingExpressions-UsingExpressionFilters

You need to specify an expected value :

```
<expression-filter evaluator="variable" expression="myVariable=true" />
```

The following should work too:

```
<expression-filter evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:myVariable=true" />
```

Comment: this worked: `<expression-filter evaluator="header" expression="INVOCATION:canSetOffering=true" />`